# yum command not loading packages from custom .repo file on CentOS 6

Tags: yum, centos6

I added a [this](http://repos.fedorapeople.org/repos/jkaluza/spectrum2/epel-spectrum2.repo) .repo file in /etc/yum.repos.d/ on CentOS 6. Then when I try to install package from this repo I do not see the mirrors loaded from this repo.

Output of `yum repolist` is

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: ftp.iitm.ac.in
 * epel: mirror01.idc.hinet.net
 * extras: ftp.iitm.ac.in
 * updates: ftp.iitm.ac.in
repo id              repo name                                            status
base                 CentOS-6 - Base                                      6,346
epel                 Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64       7,595
epel-spectrum2       Spectrum is an XMPP transport/gateway/server.           14
extras               CentOS-6 - Extras                                        4
updates              CentOS-6 - Updates                                     250
repolist: 14,209
```

So it seems like repo file is configured properly, but when I try to install a package from it, the output is

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: ftp.iitm.ac.in
 * epel: mirror01.idc.hinet.net
 * extras: ftp.iitm.ac.in
 * updates: ftp.iitm.ac.in
Setting up Install Process
No package spectrum2 available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

I'm sure the package is available in that repo, cause [their website](http://spectrum.im/projects/spectrum/wiki/Spectrum_2_-_CentOS-6RHEL-6_Packages) states it. What to do to have packages from this repo? Am I missing any settings?

Comment: what does "yum search spectrum" say?

Comment: @w00t it says `No package spectrum2 available.`

Comment: @Harry Now it should work. I've just installed and checked - all working fine.

Comment: Yes, now I can see the rpm and can install it. Are you in the development team of Spectrum 2?

Comment: No, I'm not. It's only a coincidence. I experienced the same problem with package install, and seems they have recently fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I agree their documentation says those repos make the spectrum2 packages available, but they're not there.  When I look in http://repos.fedorapeople.org/repos/jkaluza/spectrum2/epel-6/i386/ and http://repos.fedorapeople.org/repos/jkaluza/spectrum2/epel-6/x86_64 , there are no spectrum packages there.  `yum` is behaving correctly, and you will need to speak to the repository maintainers to find out what's wrong.

**Edit**: I note that the packages have since appeared in the repositories, so you should now be OK.  Yes?

Comment: yes.. there is no package named spectrum in it.

Comment: That's the point. The repo maintainer has not _actually_ placed the packages in the repository.

Answer (score 0):

Try `yum clean all` to clean all cached files.

You can also try `yum install package --enablerepo=epel-spectrum2`

Comment: Nothing worked :(

Comment: @HarryJoy Packages are available here http://repos.fedorapeople.org/repos/jkaluza/spectrum2/epel-6/SRPMS/ .. try `yum install package --enablerepo=epel-spectrum2-source`

Comment: That's an SRPM, ie a source package.  I agree that, failing all else, the OP could build from that SRPM to get a working binary RPM for local installation, but it's not a trivial process.

Comment: @MadHatter yeah its source, and it requires too much dependencies so it becomes hard to install it from source. :(